# UEFI Unetbootin alternative?

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, windows-10, unetbootin

Is there another program that can install from hard disk like how Unetbootin can? I'm trying to install from hard disk because I don't have a CD/DVD drive on my laptop or any USBs lying around. The only issue is that Unetbootin is old and only uses Legacy to boot and my Windows 10 laptop is only UEFI. I've tried using Unetbootin anyway but it take me to an error screen saying that Windows wasn't able to start. is there any thing else that I can use instead?